# Do men use "Well" to start a sentence more often than women?

Tags: word-usage, sociolinguistics

Do men use "Well" more than women to start a sentence? Is there research out there?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Sociolinguistic questions are absolutely on topic here! I doubt we'll succeed in finding much existing research on this topic, but it's certainly within this site's scope; gender differences in language use are a common topic of scholarly research.

Comment: I assume you mean sentences like "Well, I think...," not ones like "Well do I remember the days when..."

Comment: Because the women start their sentences with "Like" :)

Comment: There’s likely to be research out there. *Well* is discourse marker, so search `gender-based discourse markers`.

Comment: It's on topic but if you want an answer it helps to explain why it's interesting or why people might want to know the answer.

Comment: 1. What do you think? 2. What is the context of your question. By that I mean what event or piece of news you may have heard  spurred you to ask? 3. is there any research at all as to whether fillers such as er, um, like, well are used more by one gender than other? What about age difference? What about regionalism? What about level of education?  would an exhaustive piece of  research discard these factors?

Comment: Great question... there has been research done on the sex differences in usage of 'um' and 'uh'. [Mark Liberman of LanguageLog](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=13713) has several posts on sex differences (with -actual- data).

Comment: Why are interesting linguistic questions like this being closed?

Comment: Mari-Lou is right about this being about a single factor, and arguably hardly among the most salient, in the multivariate field of register analysis. But does that make it off-topic? I'd say decent answers would have to include data about the other factors she mentions (country as well as province etc), and see this as being a mammoth study.

Comment: Not a language question per se. A sociology or sociolect question.

Comment: @Mitch Might it be that however interesting, all Questions deserve research?